# Marionette model relationships

Tags: backbone.js, marionette, backbone.js-collections

What's the best way to define relationships inside a Marionette/Backbone application?

I know there's Backbone-relational, but it hasn't been updated for over 6 months... Is there another way to create relationships in Backbone and/or Marionette?

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

As far as i can see the only libraries that look decent are [backbone-associations](https://github.com/dhruvaray/backbone-associations) and [backbone-relational](http://backbonerelational.org/). In my opinion backbone associations is the best one since backbone relational hasn't been updated for a long time.

Comment: This [fork of backbone-relational](https://github.com/PaulUithol/Backbone-relational) has been updated more recently than backbone-associations.